# Check end of transcoding for vimeo-api?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I need to be sure by an API request that the transcoding of an uploaded video is full ended and all possible renditions are available.
I know that that the API give responses in [body][status] about

available, uploading, transcoding, uploading_error, transcoding_error

but the problem is that the status changes from 'transcoding' to 'available' in the second when the first rendition is transcoded. So how can I check by an API-Request that vimeos work has full ended and no other rendition will be added to the video in the next minutes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- If you are a PRO user and there is a specific size you are looking for you should wait for the file to appear in the files list. Waiting for "all" is not recommended because we are constantly changing and improving the list of files available.
- If you are not a PRO user, this information is not exposed at all. Once the SD version is available you will be able to generate embed codes, and shortly after that your player will have the ability to switch into HD mode (once the HD file is available).